# How to get users to login twice in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010

I have somewhat of an odd question (for me, at least).

We have some private information a department would like to place on our SharePoint farm.  The problem is, this is very sensitive information, and law demands that we have a 'two-stage' login process to secure the data.

Currently, it is housed using a system that:

A) you have to login to our network (windows logon screen)

B) you have to login to the application.

Our SharePoint farm has integrated authentication enabled.  Meaning, once you login to your computer in the morning, you never have to login to sharepoint as it already knows your credentials.

This is a problem for us.  Can we enable some sort of custom Sharepoint login?

Will this require a new web app for the site?  A new site collection only perhaps?

Thanks,

~~Kolten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called forms based authentication. Sharepoint 2010 uses claims based authentication and one of the providers you can configure is forms based. Meaning they provide a user name and password.

Here is a tutorial with the steps to do, it is a relatively straight forward process. just follow all the steps.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you move you site out of Intranet zone, then IE will automatically ask for credential everytime.

See this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063

Comment: I can't modify end user's computer configurations.  I am looking for a server side solution, if possible.  Thanks!